# To maintain session of Php files

Tags: php, html, database, oracle

I take data in forms and validate them and put them in table in database.
now the question is that i want to maintain session of the user.
mean if i give him direct link of addstudent file then he should first ask the login information then refer to add student :)

Thanks

Comment: What specifically is the problem? `$_SESSION` or database driven session

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. One of the more simple ways is to have a session variable called Login. (`$_SESSION['login']`)

On your login processing page, simply set this variable to true when the user is verified and logged in correctly. Then, on the top of any page you want to protect with login, just add this code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['login']))
{
header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
```

Example Login Process:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
if(ENTERED USERNAME CORRECT && ENTERED PASSWORD CORRECT) 
{
    $_SESSION['login'] = 1; 
}
?>
```

What this does is that when your systems verifies the login, it sets the session variable. Any pages you want to protect, the code will check to see if there is a verified login, then allow you to view the page, otherwise, it redirects you to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly **start Session** as:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
?>
```

Check whether **session** is `set` or `unset`.

**If Session is set**:

```
  if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) 
  {
  /*Code for adding student*/
  }
```

**If Session is not set:**

Ask **username** and **password**.

Compare username and password  with the database entry.

```
      if username and password matched
      {
       $_SESSION['username']=$username; //set the session variable
      /*Code for adding student*/
      }

     else
     {
        /*Re-enter username/password*/
     }
```